# Django raising no error issue

Tags: django

I'm building a simple messaging application where users can send message to each other .
I'm working a function which allows to users to send messages they previously saved as draft .

The problem is , It doesn't raise any error when no input is submitted or username doesn't exist . I think something is blocking it which mean , it wouldn't create a message to send to other user

this is my model

```
class Thread(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sender')
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='recipient')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    trash = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sentmessage = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    thread = models.ForeignKey(Thread,blank=True,null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.body
```

because you require a subject , recipient and a body to send a message and they are each in different models and this is when the user has already created the message and saved it as a draft . I have created 2 forms each with different models and populated each form with their objects.

```
class DraftForm(forms.ModelForm):
    recipient = forms.CharField(required=True,max_length=2)
    body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea,required=True,max_length=1)
    hidden_field = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())       

    class Meta:
        model = Message 
        fields = ('body',)  

    def clean_recipient(self):
            recipient = self.cleaned_data['recipient']

            try:
                recipient = User.objects.get(username=recipient)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                raise forms.ValidationError("This username does not exist")
            return recipient
class ThreadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Thread 
        fields = ('subject',)
```

views

```
@login_required
def ReadDraft(request,id):
    try:
        messages = Message.objects.get(pk=id,recipient=request.user,trash=True) 
    except Message.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('world:Display'))
    thread = Thread.objects.get(message=messages)
    initial = {}
    initial.update({'hidden_field': messages.id})
    draft = DraftForm(instance=messages,initial=initial)
    thread = ThreadForm(instance=thread)
    person = Person.objects.get(user=request.user)

    if request.method =='POST':
        id = request.POST.get('hidden_field', False)
        form = ThreadForm(request.POST)
        forms = DraftForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid and forms.is_valid():
            m = Message.objects.get(pk=id)
            recipient = form.cleaned_data['recipient']
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            body = form.cleaned_data['body']
            message =    Message.objects.create(user=request.user,recipient=recipient,body=message,thread=m.thread)

    return render(request,'create.html',{'DraftForm':draft,'ThreadForm':thread,'person':person})
```

forms

```
{% if DraftForm and ThreadForm %}

<form method="POST" >{% csrf_token %}

    {{DraftForm.recipient}}
    {{ThreadForm.subject}}
    {{DraftForm.body}}
    {{DraftForm.hidden_field}}
    <input type = "submit" value= "send" class="save" id="send"  />


</form>

{% endif %}

{{ThreadForm.subject.errors}}
{{DraftForm.recipient.errors}}
{{DraftForm.body.errors}}
```

Comment: `thread = Thread.objects.get(message=messages)`. There is no `message` field in `Thread` model. You could simply do, `thread = ThreadForm(messages.thread)`.

Comment: Have you checked your DEBUG mode is true/false inside settings.py.

Comment: @sandeep yep I checked it

Comment: @Babu but messages has a foreignkey to thread

Comment: @Babu it works , I can the message been populated but when I try to raise an error it wouldn't work

Comment: @UncleToby, you havent't provided `related_name ` for this foreign key - so access should be done by `thread.message_set` - see documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not working because here:

```
if form.is_valid and forms.is_valid()
```

One is a property and one is a method call, and only one of them is actually doing anything (the other is returning `True`).

Even if there were any errors, you don't have a condition to check if the forms fail and return the template (there is no `else` clause for your `if` check).

Putting all this together, you should have something like this:

```
if request.method =='POST':
   id = request.POST.get('hidden_field')  # get will return None as default value
   form = ThreadForm(request.POST)
   forms = DraftForm(request.POST)
   if form.is_valid() and forms.is_valid():
      # do stuff
      return redirect(reverse('some-url'))
   else:
      ctx = {'DraftForm': form, 'ThreadForm': forms}
      return render(request, 'forms.html', ctx)
else:
   return redirect(reverse('some-url'))
```

In the `forms.html`, you should have:

```
{{ DraftForm.errors }}
{{ ThreadForm.errors }}
```

Comment: ok burdan if form.is_valid and forms.is_valid() . Should I remove it?

Answer (score 2):

You do not include your forms in your template context when you doing a POST request and validation fails. So there is no error message to your form.

You should do something like:

```
if request.method =='POST':
    # some more code here ...
    thread = ThreadForm(request.POST)
    draft = DraftForm(request.POST)
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Also look at Burhans answer, you forgot the braces `if forms.is_valid()`!

Comment: Surely this will help - @UncleToby, try to avoid using the same variable name for completely different things - it's hard to analyze the code when you do `thread = Thread.objects.get(message=messages)` and then `thread = ThreadForm(instance=thread)`